# How to remove " " (quote marks) from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns Block and Lot with some records having " " at the start and end of the number. I would like to remove the " "  from the number for a report I'm writing.

There is also a space at the end of the number before the second ", for example "1234 " to 1234.

Comment: With `REPLACE`, or if you're on newer versions, with `TRIM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the characters you want to strip aren't always a space and double-quote, you could use series of `REPLACE` statements to remove those characters wherever they are.

```
UPDATE tbl set [Block] = replace(replace([Block],'"',''),' ',''),
                [Lot] = replace(replace([Lot],'"',''),' ','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to remove both trailing/leading double quotes *and* spaces, I would use `TRIM`. With a literal, that would be this:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(' "' FROM '"1234 "');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=4bf73d2cb34228b46ffbf58cca373849)

*Note, this is only available on SQL Server 2017+.*